# JavaScript Окно таймера.

Tags: javascript

Стоит вопрос,как сделать при окончании времени таймера функцию показа текста в определенном блоке.Вышло время,в правом углу,в ячейке написало 'Время вышло'.Интересует как это реализовать.Спасибо.

Comment: @Fike,нужно сделать так,что бы при окончании времени выполнялась вот такая функция : http://pastie.org/8912593
Я закомментировал куда надо вставить.
Огромное тебе спасибо!

Comment: Это не функция, это класс так записан. У него куча методов, я могу только предположить, что должно быть что-то такое:

    var actuator = new HTMLActuator();
    actuator.message(false);

Comment: @Fike,извините за настойчивость,но можно пожалуйста отредактированый код.Так-как дело с JScript имею впервые.

Comment: if (m == 0) {
      //тут вставить !
      window.location.reload();
      return;
    }

->

    if (m == 0) {
        var actuator = new HTMLActuator();
        actuator.message(false);
        window.location.reload();
        return;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@VLADPRO100LORD](/users/13947/vladpro100lord)](/users/13947/vladpro100lord), если сам таймер нигде не показывается, то достаточно

```
function showNotice() {
    var $notice = document.getElementById('notice'); // получаю элемент #notice
    $notice.style.display = 'block'; // меняю стиль на блочный
}
setTimeout(showNotice, 10000); // первый аргумент - код, который нужно выполнить (обратите внимание на отсутствие скобок), второй - количество миллисекунд, которое должно пройти перед выполнением.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, в общем как-то так:
 - назначаем интервальную функцию, которая с интервалом в одну секунду увеличивает значение таймерной переменной и результат инкремента выводит в какой-то элемент разметки;
 - для этого элемента разметки пишем соответствующий цсс-блок, который располагает его как следует;
 - одна из проверок этой интервальной функции -- достигнуто ли критическое значение, и если да, - то сбросить интервальную ф-цию и отрендерить соответствующий блочный элемент.

*Не забудьте поставить отметку "правильный ответ".*

Comment: fike,как всегда спасаете.Спасибо большое.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста дать свой вк или скайп если вам не сложно
.Есть один вопрос.

Comment: автор, вы спросили - как сделать, я ответил. Вопросы в стиле "сделайте за меня" на этом ресурсе не приветствуются.

Comment: а меня нет в вк в данный момент, вместо скайпа пользуюсь телеграмом (зверски хохочет)

Comment: @Fike Вот код,срочно нужна помощь что бы встроить сюда то что вы написали :  function startTimer() {

    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    var time = timer.innerHTML;
    var arr = time.split(":");
    var m = arr[0];
    var s = arr[1];
    if (s == 0) {
      if (m == 0) {
          //тут вставить !
          window.location.reload();
          return;
        }
      m--;
      if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
      s = 59;
    }
    else s--;
    if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = m+":"+s;
    setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
  }

Comment: нужно создать элемент, показать уже созданный или заменить значение таймера?